# jquery in how to get the children without tag id using?

Tags: javascript, jquery, table

j query in how to get the children  without tag id using ?
i have using table structure to get the children but last children not getting.

[image]

I have try this Code

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function () 
    { 
        var table = $(".data-grid-draggable").children('tbody'); 
        for (let index = 0; index < table.length; index++) 
        { 
            if (table[index].children.length != 0) 
            { 
                var tr_length = table[index].children.length;
                for (let i = 0; i <= tr_length; i++) 
                { 
                    var td_tr_values = table[index].children[i];
                } 
            } 
        } 
    });
```

Comment: please share your code for more details

Comment: $(document).ajaxComplete(function () {            
            var table = $(".data-grid-draggable").children('tbody');
            for (let index = 0; index < table.length; index++) {
                if (table[index].children.length != 0) {
                    var tr_length = table[index].children.length
                    for (let i = 0; i <= tr_length; i++) {
                        var td_tr_values = table[index].children[i]     }      }       }     });

Answer (score 0):

try this to get child in js

```
    var get_value;
    get_value = document.getElementById("container").children[0].children[0].children[0].children[0].innerText;
console.log(get_value);
```

you add more **children[0]** and get your value from table.

[click here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_children.asp) to get more about **children**